# Windows Live Photo Gallery - Order prints not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-live, windows-photo-gallery

I am trying to order prints online from **Windows Live Photo Gallery** by selecting Print, Order Prints from the menu.  My Operating System is Windows 7 RTM.

It brings up the 'Select a Printing Company' dialog, but **it doesn't show any available companies to order prints from**. This works fine under Vista or XP.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but could it not be live until October when it's released to customers?

Comment: Windows Live Photo Gallery is already available to the public - and choosing a company to print from should not be an OS-level feature.

Comment: I checked their MSDN blog and they say its OS and market dependent so if it worked before and he didn't move I am guessing it's that.  Some people have exported the registry keys from their Vista install as a temp fix for Windows 7 but it doesn't last.  I am still guessing they are ramping everything up for the official public release.

Comment: Got a link to that source?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/pix/archive/2009/03/20/microsoft-image-composite-editor-ice.aspx I don't have the registry ones open anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Windows Live Photo Gallery tries to find companies that is around your area - in your case, Phoenix, Arizona.

Maybe your area doesn't have such a supporting company as yet?

Comment: How is the accepted when you haven't moved and it worked in XP?